# Postgres before insert trigger access field of a type

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql, composite-types

In the DB, I have a type and a table that one of it's rows is that type, such as this:

```
CREATE TYPE state (last_active timestamp, ...)
CREATE TABLE devices ( state state, ... )
```

For any interaction from the device, I want to update `last_active` field in the state. I added following `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

```
create or replace function update_last_active_on_position_update_hook()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    new_state state;
begin
    if new.state IS NOT NULL then
        new.state.last_active := now();
    end if;
    RETURN new;
end
$$;
```

When I do that, I get the following error:
 `[42601] ERROR: "new.state.last_active" is not a known variable`

But if I declare a variable with type `state`, copy `new.state` to that variable, update the field and copy back; it works. Working version:

```
create or replace function update_last_active_on_position_update_hook()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    new_state state;
begin
    if new.state IS NOT NULL then
        new_state := new.state;
        new_state.last_active := now();
        new.state := new_state;
    end if;
    RETURN new;
end
$$;
```

But I don't like to do copy-update-copy. Is there another solution?

I tried to get `new.state` in parens as `(new.state).last_active` but it gives me a `syntax error near "("`

Comment: Try `(new.state).last_active`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I did, even though it works in queries, it gives me syntax error. See the last sentence

Comment: I just tried your code on my 14.1 PostgreSLQ database, and it works like a charm. Which version are you using? Normal PostgreSQL or a fork?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 12. Last snippet works, first one gives me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with snippet 1 in Postgres 12:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f1f0f051925445f16ed51b69e9995cf4)*

This is clearly a shortcoming of PL/pgSQL. But no need to report it as it has been **fixed in Postgres 14**. See:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4b7d8f123ff646cd5ea2160d90fc8853)*

[The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.6.5.9)

> - Improve PL/pgSQL's [**expression**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-expressions.html) and [**assignment**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) parsing (Tom Lane)
>
>   This change allows assignment to array slices and nested record fields.

In particular, [Tom Lane commented](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRDi-WT2VaR+DpyAe+H3Pf9xgAozSj+SzhrZYuFSZ3u_Jw@mail.gmail.com):

> 0005 adds documentation and test cases.  It also fixes a couple of
> pre-existing problems that the plpgsql parser had with assigning to
> sub-fields of record fields, which I discovered while making the
> tests.

#### Workaround

> But I don't like to do copy-update-copy. Is there another solution?

Here is a workaround for Postgres 13 or earlier:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_last_active_on_position_update_hook()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _state state;
BEGIN
   NEW.state := json_populate_record (NEW.state, json_build_object('last_active', now()));  -- !!
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5a18ec5724eb4850aa99cf63150ddea)*

See:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782641/939860)

Better? Faster? Not sure. A bit shorter in any case.

While being at it, I moved the condition into a `WHEN` clause in the trigger definition. This way, the trigger function is only even called when needed. That's cheaper:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo
BEFORE UPDATE ON devices
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.state IS NOT NULL)
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_last_active_on_position_update_hook();
```

See:

- [Is it possible to dynamically loop through a table's columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742016/939860)